# Calcular un monto usando un datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Tengo 2 fechas, y estoy calculando la diferencia entre ambas, y por ejemplo la diferencia me da 00:10:05 osea, 10 minutos y 5 segundos.

Ahora bien, yo necesito saber si puedo multiplicar por $10 cada segundo (605 segundos por 10 pesos) por lo cual al imprimir el resultado debiese indicarme $6050.

```
import datetime

hora = '2019-04-13 10:39:22'
hora1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(hora, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
horaformat = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
hora2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(horaformat, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dif=hora2-hora1
print(dif)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes saber el número total de segundos de un Date con la función `total_seconds()`, luego solo tendrías que multiplicar el resultado por el número que quieras.

```
dif.total_seconds() 
total = dif.total_seconds() * 10
```

Comment: Gracias! me funcionó